# Change specific values within a column based on keyword

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following column in a dataframe:

```
'Marital-status'

'Never-married'
'Married-civ-spouse'
'Separated'
'Married-army-spouse'
'Divorced'
'Widowed'
```

I want to just lump together obs that are separated or divorced and married regardless of what comes after. (ie. I want 'Married-civ-spouse' and 'Married-army-spouse' to be labeled 'Married'. I want 'Separated' and 'Divorced' to be labeled 'Separated') The other columns such as Never-married and Widowed I want to stay the same.

I have tried figuring it out starting with

```
if 'Married-' in df.['Marital-status']:
```

but I am not sure how to easily replace all the values with the value I want.

Comment: `df.['Marital-status]` is mixing syntax. Either access the column as an attribute or use the dictionary syntax. As it is, this cannot work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the cells on `'-'` and take the first part. First define a mask so you don't mess up other rows like `'Never-married'`.

```
m = df['Marital-status'].str.contains('Married')
df.loc[m, 'Marital-status'] = df.loc[m, 'Marital-status'].str.split('-').str[0]
df['Marital-status'] = df['Marital-status'].replace('Divorced', 'Separated')

  Marital-status
0  Never-married
1        Married
2      Separated
3        Married
4      Separated
5        Widowed
```